# How to customize master page with fixed width (SharePoint 2010)?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, custom-masterpage

My previous question was closed. I want to have a master page with fixed width. I tried to set the margins for the master page as follows,

```
/*css*/
body 
{
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
}
```

After this, the sharepoint site displays the margin in the left but not the right margin. I want my sharepoint site to look like these http://healthvermont.gov/enviro/asbestos/index.aspx and http://www.choosemyplate.gov/myplate/index.aspx .

Like http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com: Empty spaces on the left and right side and content (including) in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom Wilson has a great blog post about how to accomplish this: http://styledpoint.com/blog/fixed-width-centered-aligned-sharepoint-2010-site-updated/

He gives a bunch of examples of how to make this work, but the basic example is:

```
#s4-bodyContainer {
width: 950px !important;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: it actually does the job perfectly. But site actions ribbon is still fills the browser. Is there anyway we can shrink that too? and How can I set the color to gray in the margins?

Comment: For the site actions, the article has a jQuery solution.  For the gray color, you would need to set the background color of the body to the gray color and then the background color of the bodycontainer class to white.

Comment: Got it. Worked perfectly.