# SP13: Master Page Centering

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, javascript, master-page

I am working changing the master page to center the content in the middle of the page. For an example, see the homepage to www.topsharepoint.com.  To accomplish this task I have changed the master page margins with the div text.  For sample code used, see below.

```
<div id="s4-workspace" 
text-align: center; 
width: 30px; 
Padding-left: 30px"
```

The following are the problems I am having:

1. When you change the size of the internet window the centering becomes distorted. Do I need to change the display = fixed?
2. I could be approaching this the incorrect and hardest way.  If I change the format to Oslo or blue vertical, can I achieve this without changing the master page code?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: check this one, i think this is what you want http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60320/how-to-customize-master-page-with-fixed-width-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 1):

No, this is exactly what the masterpage is designed for. You're going about it the completely wrong way though. These are CSS customizations.

Add the following somewhere in the header:

```
<style>
#s4-workspace{
    width:1024px;
    margin:auto;
}
</style>
```

Modify accordingly

Also, go through a CSS tutorial to explain to you the basics:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/ . CSS will really augment your masterpage customizations 10fold, very much recommended in learning it.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend upon how your master page is structured. A neat way would be add a new div wrapper inside #s4-workspace and add the CSS for the wrapper class.

[image]

Include the css/reference from the master page:

```
/* For Fixed Width */
div.wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 1000px;
}

/* For Fluid Width */
div.wrapper {
    margin: auto 5% !important;
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

SharePoint dynamically resizes s4-workspace, you have to be careful adding CSS to this div. Once you make these changes, make sure you test the SharePoint dialog/modal boxes too.